# multi line entry for event in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

How do make multi line entry appear for event in fullcalendar. Currently it cuts of in single line . I also make more info appear on hover .

I tried eventRender but it's saying there is no such option

The version I am using is 5.3.0 and from CDN

```
    var calendarEl          = document.getElementById(calendarID);
    var calendar            = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    handleWindowResize  : true,
                    expandRows          : true,
                    height              : height,
                    windowResize        : function(arg) {
                        if (self.isMaximized() === false) {
                            self.calendar.updateSize();
                        }
                    },                
                    eventRender: function(info) {
                        var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                          title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                          placement : 'top',
                          trigger   : 'hover',
                          container : 'body'
                        });
                    },
                    headerToolbar       : {
                      left              : 'prev,next today',
                      center            : 'title',
                      right             : 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,,'
                    },
                    navLinks            : true,  
                    businessHours       : false,  
                    editable            : false,
                    selectable          : false,
                    events              : self.events
                })
```

Comment: Unknown option 'eventRender'

Comment: Added code abaove

Comment: eventRender is from old versions. Did you take a moment to check the current documentation? You will find https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks instead